# ScrollViewer border moves out when HorizontalScrollBarVisibility set to "Auto" or "Visible"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, scroll

In XAML I have a ScrollView and a ListView inside.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0, 0, 0, 2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
      <ListView  BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Name="listAnswers">

...
/>
```

So, when I remove the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility tag, 
my border is unmovable while scrolling, but if I set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
to "Auto" or "Visible" vertical Red border moves out and disappears.

How to enable scrollbar and set its border unmovable?

Pictures:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f2446d54ab.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f2446d54ab.jpg)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a5bfe72b5e.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a5bfe72b5e.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use padding instead of border:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0, 0, 0, 2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Padding="3" Background="Red">
    <ListView Name="listAnswers" MinWidth="300"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Not quite so, the red border encloses a scroll bar as well, but it must be inside as is shown on pictures.

The thing is ListView has it's own border and it disappears with HorizontalScrollBarVisibility set on scrolling, I don't understand why.

Comment: Ok, I already have seen the picture. Give me a minute to check some solution :)

Comment: Dmitry, I have changed my answer, please try another solution.

Comment: Yes, as to the red border, it works, thanks.
But in regard to own border of listview, it's not fit, I should've given a real case for example.

Please, remove the red border at all and try it out again concerning the own border of Listview inside of ScrollViewer.

If HorizontalScrollBarVisibility is set to "Auto" or "Visible" the ListView border starts moving on scrolling.

Comment: Well, I think it'd be better to set ListView width to a fixed value to fit inside of scrollviewer, it fixes the problem.